# Правильная навигация в iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Есть приложение под android, хотелось бы сделать такое же под iOS, но никак не могу понять как правильно все это расположить на storyboard

Приложение при включении показывает splashscreen во время которого происходит загрузка данных по сети, и только после этого открывается основное окно приложения. В iOS я так понял сплэшскрин это только картинка и во время ее показа нельзя ничего делать? Хорошо, дублирую вью в приложении, делаю его похожим на сплэшскрин.

Основное окно приложения имеет внизу таббар - скорее всего тут подойдет таб бар контроллер? Как вызвать из контроллера который загружает данные и сплэшскрин таб бар контроллер?

Само основное окно приложения вызывает вьюхи не только из табов, но и из другого меню. Как их правильно помещать на сторибоард?

Comment: Можно чуть больше деталей про "другое меню"? в приложении две не связанных навигации? или как между собой связаны табы и второй вариант навигации?

Comment: Ну допустим одна и таже вью вызывается из таббар контроллера по кнопке внизу и из одного из пунктов "меню" в другой вьюхе которая в этом же таббар контролере.  т.е фактически у вьюхи которая вызывается по клику на второй таб должна быть кнопка назад которая ведет на первый таб. Пока решаю это зашив в коде вьюхи, но кажеться этот подход не совсем верный?

Comment: Скорее всего вам понадобится `UINavigationController`. Не совсем уверен где именно его лучше всего поставить. Либо с него начать и к нему прицепить `UITabBar`, либо `UITabBarController` и каждый таб в нем делать `UINavigationController`ом. Либо какая-то другая комбинация всего выше указанного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу оговорюсь: то, что вы хотите сделать я бы не назвал "правильной навигацией в iOS".

Если я правильно понимаю, что вам надо, это несколько табов, каждый из которых представляет собой иерархию из нескольких экранов. И с любого уровня вложенности из любой иерархии можно перескочить на любой уровень другой иерархии.

- Как организовать табы

Как я указывал в комментарии ранее, вам надо создать `UITabBarController` и к каждому табу привязать `UINavigationController` с иерархией экранов. Вроде такого:
[image: сториборд]
При таком сетапе вы получаете кнопку back сверху слева на всех экранах после root. чтобы програмно переключаться между табами используйте

```
self.tabBar.selectedIndex = NEW_INDEX;
```

- Переход между произвольными экранами

Если, например, вам надо перейти между двумя не связанными экранами вы можете либо:

просто добавлять нужный вью контроллер наверх в текущую иерархию. Из текущего вью контроллера вызывайте

```
pushViewController:(UIViewController * _Nonnull)viewController
              animated:(BOOL)animated
```

в этой ситуации кнопка back вернет вас на тот экран с которого вы пришли, но это может запутать пользователя, поскольку back в разных ситуациях вернет его на разные экраны.

другой вариант сделать свой класс наследованный от `UITabBarController` и в нем имплементировать метод, который переключит на другой таб, и создаст иерархию вью контроллеров до нужной вложенности + передаст все данные которые должен получить новый контроллер. Таким образом если пользователь нажмет back он вернется на предыдущий экран в контексте текущего таба.

Например, если мне надо со второго таба перейти на первый таб и открыть третий вью контроллер в иерархии, то я передаю индекс таба и индекс контроллера. В результате я вижу первый таб активным и третий контроллер на экране. Нажатие back вернет меня на второй конроллер в иерархии текущего таба.

- как сделать копию сплэш скрина в приложении.

Я бы предложил из `UITabBarController` при первом открытии вызывать модальный экран, с `UIImageView` копирующим сплэш. Не забыть спрятать statusBar. когда загрузка закончена просто убирать модальный экран.

- если такой подход не является "правильной навигацией", то как сделать правильную?

Я бы предложил попытаться перестроить приложение таким образом, чтобы с одного таба, не важно насколько глубоко в иерархии находится пользователь, ему не надо было открывать экраны глубже рута другого таба. Например, если первый таб - покупка билетов, то пользователь проходит через несколько экранов, где выбирает тип билета, вводит инфо о способе оплаты и так далее. После того, как билет куплен, пользователь сразу хочет его использовать - это первый экран таба использования билета.

Либо, все экраны, которые не принадлежат одной иерархии, и могут равноценно использоваться в нескольких, делать модальными и не привязывать к какому то конкретному табу.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант я вам предлагаю не помещать "фейковый" сплешскрин в иерархию вьюконтроллеров, а просто продублировать его, положив UIImageView поверх контента и спрятать в нужный вам момент.